# Which short answers are correct?

Tags: word-order

**A. I have never been to New Jersey.**

Neither have I.

I haven’t either.

I haven’t too.

I neither.

Me neither.

1. All of these answers are correct (grammatical)?
2. Please sort these answers in descending order of formality.

---

**B. I have been to New Jersey.**

So have I.

I have, too.

I too.

Me too.

1. All of these answers are correct (grammatical)?
2. Please sort these answers in descending order of formality.

---

**C. I didn’t want to buy it.**

Neither did I.

He didn’t either.

She didn’t too.

They neither.

It too.

1. All of these answers are correct (grammatical)?
2. Please sort these answers in descending order of formality.

Comment: What do _you_ think is right? This isn't a homework-help site, so letting us know how you've already approached the problem would be nice.

Comment: **Are all these answers correct?** A i and ii are correct, iii and iv incorrect, v informal.

Comment: @CDR No, it's not a homework! I made these sentences

Comment: [I **made up those sentences** or I wrote those sentences.] The question is a bit obnoxious but a lot of learners need this.

Comment: neither or nor can be used. You need to go and look up these usages before asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. i and ii are correct, iii and iv incorrect, v is informal.

B. All are grammatical, but *Me too* is informal and *I too* would only be used as part of a formal, longer sentence. "I too have visited New Jersey".

C. i and ii are correct, the others incorrect.

It's impossible to put them in order of formality.

Comment: I can't be bothered to check each one of yours. Maybe you should write them out.

Comment: Why "Me neither" is correct but "They neither" isn't?

Comment: @Lambie please rehash it

Comment: **Why is "Me neither" correct but "They neither" not?** Real people say "Me neither" in informal speech - nobody says "They neither".

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Kate, I'd appreciate it if you would refrain from answering questions that are clearly off-topic and poor quality. There are fourteen homework questions in one, plus three requests to sort. There isn't even a question about learning English, and answers like this one aren't great because someone else with a similar question won't know why those answers are correct. As Lambie points out, few people are going to check all those answers.

Comment: @gotube - OK - but the OP does say that it isn't homework!

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks! By "homework", I meant homework-type questions, that's to say, questions that aren't about English, but test one's abilities in English. The OP posted them as *our* homework.

Comment: @gotube All my questions are about learning english.

Comment: @PetrVatov I understand that you're asking the question *to help you learn English*, but that's not the same as a question *about English*. A question about English asks about **some aspect of English**, like a specific grammar point, the usage of specific expressions, the meaning of a sentence in context, etc. If you're trying to learn about **short answers**, for instance, frame your question about that. Explain to us what you already know, and what aspect you're unsure about. Check any recent questions by [Loviii](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/82229/loviii) for some examples.